# How to prove by induction(do not use differential) $(1-x)^{-n}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\binom{n-1+k}{k}x^k$

Tags: combinatorics

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem.

Q: How to prove by induction(do not use differential)
$$(1-x)^{-n}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\binom{n-1+k}{k}x^k$$

I tried to solve by $\binom{n+k}{k}=\binom{n-1+k}{k}+\binom{n-1+k}{k-1}$ this problem but i can't get the right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: For the induction step you have

$$\begin{align*}
(1-x)^{-(n+1)}&=(1-x)^{-n}(1-x)^{-1}\\
&=\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n-1+k}kx^k\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}1\cdot x^n\right)\;.
\end{align*}$$

This is a [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product); the coefficient of $x^n$ in the product is therefore

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n-1+k}k\cdot1=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n-1+k}k=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n-1+k}{n-1}\;.$$

Now use a standard identity to complete the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Check that for $n=1,2,3$ the relation holds, then suppose it's true for $$(1-x)^{-n}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\binom{n-1+k}{k}x^k$$

Now let's see what this gives us:
$$(1-x)^{-(n+1)}=(1-x)^{-n}\times\frac1{1-x}=\left(\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\binom{n-1+k}{k}x^k\right)\times\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$$ then use the Cauchy product.

Comment: Very curious: the two answers that use induction, as required by the statement of the problem, are the two that someone has downvoted.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Curious things often occur here. Recently, I've answered a question that got two downvotes within a few seconds of posting it, then got 9 upvotes and was accepted as the answer...

Comment: They do indeed, though the one that you describe is definitely odder than most!

Answer (score 0):

So the following method does not use induction as the OP asks, but this method can be helpful in similar problems.

It is equivalent to show that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {n-1+k \choose k} x^k (1-x)^n = 1. 
$$
Let us prove this identity for any $x \in [0,1)$.

Consider the following game: flip a biased coin (probability of heads is $x$ and probability of tails is $1-x$) until we flip $n$ tails. Consider the event that you finish on the $(n+k)$th flip for some $k \geq 0$. In particular, note that you flipped $n$ tails and $k$ heads at this point and the last flip *must* have been tails. For any specific sequence of admissible coin flips for this event (e.g. $HH\ldots HHTT\ldots TT$), the probability of this sequence is precisely $x^k (1-x)^n$. Now the number of admissible sequences is 
$$
{n-1+k \choose k},
$$
because the $(n+k)$th flip is necessarily tails; so we can then distribute the $k$ heads among any of the $n-1+k$ earlier flips. Hence the probability that we flip exactly $n+k$ coins is
$$
{n-1+k \choose k}x^k (1-x)^n.
$$

For different $k$, these events are disjoint, so the infinite sum above is the probability of the event that at some point we finished (i.e. we do not roll an infinite number of times). In particular,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {n-1+k \choose k}x^k (1-x)^n = 1 - P\left(\text{flip at most }n-1\text{ tails in }\infty\text{-many flips}\right).
$$
It is not too hard to see that this latter probability is $0$, which finishes off the proof of the identity.

[To see that this last probability is zero, note that the probability that you flip more than $n*m$ coins is *at most* $(1-(1-x)^n)^m$, which tends to zero as $m \to \infty$]