# Prove the following power series solution

Tags: combinatorics

Prove the following power series equality:

$$\sum_{n\geq0} {n \choose k-1} x^{n} = x^{k-1}/(1-x)^k $$

I'm not sure if I am on the right track, but I tried answering this through induction on k. With base case  k = 1. I got  $$\sum_{n>=0}x^{n} = (1-x)^{-1} $$ which holds. When I try for m + 1 I get
$$ x^{m}/((1-x)^m(1-x)) $$ but im not sure how to continue from here. I was thinking of writing the bottom half of the fraction as a sum, but I'm not sure what I would do with the x^m term

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove by induction(do not use differential) $(1-x)^{-n}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\binom{n-1+k}{k}x^k$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1866316/how-to-prove-by-inductiondo-not-use-differential-1-x-n-sum-infty-k)

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{n \geq 0}{n \choose k - 1}x^{n}} & =
\sum_{n = k - 1}^{\infty}{n  \choose k - 1}x^{n} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{n + k - 1 \choose k - 1}x^{n + k - 1} =
x^{k - 1}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{n + k - 1 \choose n}x^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
x^{k - 1}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-n - k + 1 +n - 1 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}x^{n} =
x^{k - 1}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-k \choose n}\pars{-x}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
x^{k - 1}\bracks{1 + \pars{-x}}^{-k} =
\color{#f00}{x^{k - 1} \over \pars{1 - x}^{k}}
\end{align}